# Dynamic height() with window resize()

Tags: jquery, reactjs

I am working in task which need to implement the below jquery function in ReactJS. I cant find any solution for this.

```js
$(window).resize(function() {
    $('#content').height($(window).height() - 46);
});

$(window).trigger('resize');
```

```css
html, body {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

.bg {
    width:315px;
    height:23px;
    margin:0 auto;
    text-indent:9000px;
}

#bg1 {background:url(http://placehold.it/200x300) 0 50% no-repeat;}
#bg2 {background:url(http://placehold.it/200x300) 0 50% no-repeat;}

#content {
    width:450px; 
    margin:0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="bg1" class="bg">top</div>
    <div id="content">
        Content
    </div>
<div id="bg2" class="bg">bottom</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Javascript in your LifeCycle methods to be able to do this.

```
componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener("resize", this.updateDimensions);
}
componentWillUnmount() { /* Make sure you remove all the listeners inside willUnmount method */
    window.removeEventListener("resize", this.updateDimensions);
}
updateDimensions = () => {
    /* Your code to set the properties go here */
}
```

Additionally, you can try avoiding mutating the DOM directly in `updateDimensions` method. You can either use `refs` or you can have a `property` on the state, whose value will be updated inside the `updateDimensions` method. You can then set the property as your `style` in the component whose height needs to change.

Answer (score 0):

Since the calculation you do is fixed and depends on the viewport height, i would use CSS alone.

```
#content{
    height: calc(100vh - 46px);
}
```

---

Updated code

```css
html, body {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
}

.bg {
    width:315px;
    height:23px;
    margin:0 auto;
    text-indent:9000px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

#bg1 {background:url(http://placehold.it/200x300) 0 50% no-repeat;}
#bg2 {background:url(http://placehold.it/200x300) 0 50% no-repeat;}

#content {
    width:450px; 
    margin:0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    
    height: calc(100vh - 46px);
}
```

```html
<div id="bg1" class="bg">top</div>
    <div id="content">
        help me. seriously.
    </div>
<div id="bg2" class="bg">bottom</div>
```